# Embedding font in AS3 classes

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I am a newbie on as3,the problem I am facing is,I am trying to embed font in my game.I have embeded font png and its xml in Assets.as AS

```
[Embed(source = "../media/font/font.png")]          
public static const font:Class;         
[Embed(source="../media/font/font.fnt",mimeType="application/octet stream")]        
public static const fontxml:Class;
```

I have used this font and fontxml in my HUD.as 's onadded to stage function somthing like

```
var bitmap:Bitmap = new font(); //error
var texture:Texture = Texture.fromBitmap(bitmap);
var xml:XML = XML(new fontxml()); //error
```

but the font and the fontxml are creating poblem,the error is "Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: font" I cannot find the solution to this error,any suggestions?

Comment: From HUD.as, call `new Assets.font()` since font is a static member of another class. Same for `Assets.fontxml`.

Comment: great, I posted an answer for you to validate then :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calling a public static function or property from another class, you must specify the class it belongs to:

```
new Assets.font();
```

Answer (score 0):

In as3 you must use a font file format like .ttf or .otf not a png file.

try this:

```
[Embed(source = "../media/font/font.ttf")]
public static const font:Class;
.
.
.
var tf:Textformat = new Textformat();
tf.font = new font().fontName;
```